# spring integration specific channels

Tags: spring, spring-integration

what is the relation to the channels :
 DirectChannel, QueueChannel, ExecutorChannel, PriorityChannel, RendezvousChannel,  PublishSubscribeChannel  to integration components in case the best approach to use them ?

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 first class citizen in Spring Integration: Endpoint, Channel and Handler. The endpoint gets data from the channel to handle it in the handler.

Different channel types serve for different approaches to get data from it by the endpoint.

`DirectChannel` is very simple and its data is handled directly from the caller's thread. Like in simple raw Java - main -> service method.

`QueueChannel` is for buffering data in the internal queue. The endpoint polls data from there int its desired pace.

`ExecutorChannel` just shifts the data to the free thread of the configured `Executor`. Then handler is called on that thread already.

`PriorityChannel` is similar to the `QueueChannel`, but with the order capability for that data which is stored in the internal queue in the moment of send.

`RendezvousChannel` is fully based on the `SynchronousQueue` from Java.

`PublishSubscribeChannel` provides a-la `topic` implementation - all the handlers will get the same message.

More info on the matter in the documentation and JavaDocs.

Also don't forget about theory on the matter: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

Comment: Also see [Messaging Channels](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html) in the reference manual for descriptions of each type.